# Copying a Magento site

Tags: deployment, magento, copy

How easy/hard is it to make a carbon copy of a Magento site?

My company have developed a UK site for a client using Magento. This has proven to be popular, so the client has now they've requested for a US version of the site be made. So far as I'm aware, the site will be 99% the same, just pointing to a different database (for different products), and maybe a few copy changes. There will not be any integration between the two sites, which will both be self contained entities.

The problem is that the developer who built the site has left the company, so I've been given the task of making this copy.

If there is any sanity in the world, then it should be a case of copying the files/database, updating a couple of config items, and bob's your unkle - but with everything I've heard about Magento, it's not going to be this easy.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? Thank you :)

**UPDATE:** I don't know if this makes any difference, but we're using the Community Edition of the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it should be a case of copying the files/database, updating a couple of config items, 
>   and bob's your unkle

Yep, that's basically it.

You'll have to change the domain name in the database table `core_config_data`, adjust database connection parameters in `app/etc/local.xml`, delete the contents of `var/cache`, and you're ready to roll: Log into the backend and change what you want.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I tried that and it all appears to have worked fine. I went a little further than just emptying cache, I also emptied minifycache, report and session (based on a video I found somewhere) - No idea what difference that would make, but like I say, it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you?

Magento is designed to use for multiple stores, each with his own configuration. Just create a new store view for the US webshop and customize specific configuration in the backend.

If you make a copy you will need to maintain two repositories which makes maintenance hard

Comment: To be honest, it's not up to me - I think we've had so much trouble with Magento that we don't even want to attempt that.